# I'm using PyInstaller to compile a program that uses skbio. "import skbio" is not being incorporated into the executable version. How can I solve?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, skbio

I developed a python program that uses skbio (scikit-bio). The program works correctly on my computer. I used PyInstaller to compile my program and forced --hidden-import (py -m PyInstaller MYSCRIPT.py --additional-hooks-dir=. --hidden-import="skbio" --onefile --noconsole). The compilation does not give any errors, but it does not incorporate the package. When I run the .exe version on another computer it gives ModuleNotFoundError skbio.io.format (my code doesn't even use this part of the package).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqZ7r.png)